# Extendable piecewise function for any number of knots/breaks

Tags: r

I have the following collection of slopes, breaks, and intercepts:

```
slopes <- c(4, 2, 8, 4)
breaks <- c(0.0150, 0.030, 0.035)
intercepts <- c(0.0299, 0.0599, -0.1201, 0.0199)
```

They define the following lines:

```
# y = slopes[1] * x + intercepts[1]
# y = slopes[2] * x + intercepts[2]
# y = slopes[3] * x + intercepts[3]
# y = slopes[4] * x + intercepts[4]
```

Graphing the lines yields:

```
tibble(x = seq(0.0025, 0.06, 0.0025), y = x) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point(alpha = 0) + 
    geom_abline(intercept = intercepts[1], slope = slopes[1], color = "red") + 
    geom_abline(intercept = intercepts[2], slope = slopes[2], color = "orange") + 
    geom_abline(intercept = intercepts[3], slope = slopes[3], color = "yellow") +
    geom_abline(intercept = intercepts[4], slope = slopes[4], color = "green2") +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1))
```

[image]

I'd like to create a piecewise function based on the lines and breaks/knots, like so (follow: red -> orange -> yellow -> green):

[image]

I could wrap a function over a couple of if/else statements to get what I want. But I'd like for the solution to be extendable for any number of breaks/knots (instead of just 3, in this example).

How might I accomplish this?

Comment: So each break marks a transition to the next slope/intercept?

Comment: @JohnColeman That's correct. If `x <= breaks[1]` then `y = slopes[1] * x + intercepts[1]`; if `x > breaks[1] & x <= breaks[2]` then `y = slopes[2] * x + intercepts[2]`... etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fairly extensible:

```
piecewise <- function(x, slopes, intercepts, breaks) {
    i = 1 + findInterval(x, breaks)
    y = slopes[i] * x + intercepts[i]
    return(y)
}
```

Note that I put the `breaks` argument last, since that seemed most natural to me.
It automatically implements the piecewise defined function for any number of pieces.

Example:

```
slopes <- c(4, 2, 8, 4)
intercepts <- c(0.0299, 0.0599, -0.1201, 0.0199)
breaks <- c(0.0150, 0.030, 0.035)

df <- tibble(x = seq(0.0025, 0.06, 0.0025)) %>% 
    mutate(y = piecewise(x, slopes, intercepts, breaks))

df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: @emehex Good edit. I come from a functional programming background so tend to find it natural to return functions, but code which can be more easily vectorized is better in R. I'm still trying to get the idioms down.